# Firebase Auth + FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

My usecase it to send a push-notification to a user using the Firebase Auth UID to all the devices he is signed-in. Since firebase Auth is managing the user sessions,

1. Is there a way to directly send a FCM notification just using the uid of the user? Or
2. Is there a way to fetch the registration ids of all signed-in devices for a given uid?

This looks like standard requirement, for example to update the 'Order Status' to a user. If available this could be pretty powerful, and could greatly simplify direct messaging requirements (e-commerce, chat etc) where the user gets notified on web/android/ios.

If this is not possible, any suggestions on the standard way to acquire/manage the registrations_ids of a given user is appreciated.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box but you can build the mechanism.
You need to maintain a `uid` specific deviceGroup and all the registration ID per device that belongs to it.

Each time a user signs in with Firebase, you get the device registration ID and the user's ID token and send it to your backend. You verify the ID token and get the `uid` from it, you then add that registration ID to that user's device group.

Each time a user signs out, you remove their registration ID from the signed out user's device group.

When you want to send a push notification to a specified user, you can send it to the user's device group ID.

This is the simplified version but there are a bunch of edge cases you have to deal with to keep the device group for a user in sync so no notification is sent to a signed out user.